# How to make an Object collide with another Object and make it do a task?

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode, uiimageview

I am developing a game on Xcode, but I ran into a problem. I'm not able to make my objectGuy
from going beyond a roof and I am unable to make my objectGuy from falling beyond the floor.

This is what I tried coding: I need help making the collision stop the jump and make the objectGuy fall back down and once it collides with the ground, to keep him there.

**topGround** is referring to the roof / **bottomGround** is referring to the ground

```
-(void) collision {
    if (CGRectIntersectsRect(guy.frame, topGround.frame)) {
        guyJump = 0;
    }

    if (CGRectIntersectsRect(guy.frame, bottomGround.frame)) {
       guy.center = CGPointMake(guy.center.x, 261);
    }
}

-(void) touchesBegan:(NSSet *)touches withEvent:(UIEvent *)event {
    guyJump = 20;
    [self collision]; 
}

-(void) guyMoving {
    guy.center = CGPointMake(guy.center.x, guy.center.y - guyJump);
    guyJump = guyJump - 5;

    if (guyJump < -3) {
        guyJump = -3;
    }
 }
```

Comment: Unless this is for an exercise, you should really consider using [`SpriteKit`](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/GraphicsAnimation/Conceptual/SpriteKit_PG/Introduction/Introduction.html) (or any other 2D game engine)

Comment: Everyone tells me to look at SpriteKit, but I don't know how to use it, I just need to code this collision. @Alladinian

Comment: Yup, SpriteKit is the best tool for this job. If you don't know the framework, it's time to learn from Apple's documentation https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/GraphicsAnimation/Conceptual/SpriteKit_PG/Introduction/Introduction.html or one of the many tutorials on the web https://www.google.com/search?q=spritekit++tutorial&oq=spritekit++tutorial&aqs=chrome..69i57j0l3.6206j0j1&sourceid=chrome&ie=UTF-8 You'll save yourself a lot of time in the long run.

Comment: I solved it by coding a simple line. @BergQuester but thanks and I know it would help but I don't see how to code for spritekit